# Find a file and it's path in a directory, file name given in argv[2] from terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, file, ubuntu

Here I list all the files and their type from a directory given in terminal. I want to give a file name in the terminal, and if the file exists in that folder, I want to print it's name and the path to it. How could I do it?

```
void listDir(char *dirName){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dirEntry;
    struct stat inode;
    char name[1000];

    dir=opendir(dirName);
    if(dir==0){
        printf("Error in opening the directory\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while((dirEntry=readdir(dir))!=0){
        sprintf(name, "%s/%s", dirName, dirEntry->d_name);

        lstat(name, &inode);

        if(S_ISDIR(inode.st_mode)){
            printf("This is a directory: ");
        }
        else if(S_ISREG(inode.st_mode)){
            printf("This is a file: ");
        }
        else if(S_ISLNK(inode.st_mode)){
            printf("This is a link: ");
        }

        printf("%s\n", dirEntry->d_name);

    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    struct stat fileMetadata;

    if(stat(argv[1], &fileMetadata) < 0){
        printf("Error in getting information about the file");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(S_ISDIR(fileMetadata.st_mode)){ //it's a directory
        printf("The content of %s (directory) is:\n", argv[1]);
        listDir(argv[1]);
    }   
    else{
        printf("%s it's not a directory\n", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will search the filename in all the possible directories and sub directory.
filename is given at commandline.
replace your listDir() function to this (this will search the file name in all directories and subdirectories and print its absolute path):

```
void listDir(char * dirName, char *fileName)
{
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *dirEntry;
        struct stat inode;
        char name[1000];
        char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];

        dir=opendir(dirName);
        if(dir==0)
        {
                printf("Error in opening the directory\n");
        }
        printf("file_name : %s\n",fileName);
        while((dirEntry=readdir(dir))!=0)
        {
                if(strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, fileName) == 0)
                {
                        realpath(dirEntry->d_name, buf);
                        printf ("[%s]\n", buf);
                }

        }
}
```

for realpath() function include this header files:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <limits.h>
```